# Adding list items from XML file

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xml

I'm currently exporting XML files from my ERP system and they look like this :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <ISA xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ISA_Info field="ISA.FullPath" value="\\nas\apps\test\PDF\AKF000210460100051.pdf"/>
    <ISA_Info field="ISA.Customer" value="Test Customer"/>
    <ISA_Info field="ISA.Type" value="AKF"/><ISA_Info field="Meta.Categorie" value="INS"/><ISA_Info field="Meta.Doc.Date" value="08/06/2010"/>
    <ISA_Info field="Meta.FileNumber" value="021046"/>
    <ISA_Info field="Meta.Year" value="2010"/>
    <ISA_Info field="Meta.Description" value=" Installatie P360 scanner"/></ISA>
```

I have created a list inside sharepoint 2013 for my customers. Is there a way to add the customer value to my list? I had an app that could do this in SP 2007 but the person who created this app isn't here anymore. In the future I would like to be able that when I click on the customer, a document library opens and shows all files related to the customer. Maybe if possible it should add the document automatically to the right customer.
Thanks !

Comment: you could create a timerjob that import the xml to a list

Comment: but i only want the cusomer name from the xml file to be added in my list

Comment: you could create a custom action that import the file

Comment: how do I do this? I'm kind of new to SharePoint myself so I don't know much about the functionalities it contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try this code to implement in some kind of app wish me luck !

```
public void UpdateSharePointListFromXML()
        {
        string filename = Server.MapPath("XMLFile1.xml");
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.Load(filename);
        XmlNodeList topM = xmldoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes;
        foreach (XmlElement element in topM)
        {
            if (element.Name == "ISA_Info")
            {
                Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    SPSite site = new SPSite("http://jack-7716f30e37:2012");
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        SPList list = web.Lists["MyList"];
                        SPListItem Item = list.Items.Add();
                        Item["field"] = element.Attributes[0].Value.ToString();
                        Item["Value"] = element.Attributes[1].Value.ToString();
                        Item.Update();
                        list.Update();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```